# CSS: Dropdown behind Div / Z-Index dont solve it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

i got a Problem with my Website. a bootstrap css Dropdown button menu is expanding behind a div. you can see it here (in the right sidebar there is a button with the value "Wähle Kanton"):

http://www.fitness-center24.ch/thurgau

i already gave the  tag already a z-index of 9999, but unfortunately this dont solve my Problem.

thanks for your help.

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Wähle Kanton <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="z-index: 9999;">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT: i added "Position: relative" to the ul tag, but now the div around the the Dropdown is expanding when you open the Dropdown. is there a way that the Dropdown expanding "over" all elements without pushing them down?

Comment: remove `overflow:hidden;` in `.moduletable, div[class^="moduletable-"], div[class*=" moduletable-"] {`  in joomla.css

Answer (score 0):

Remove overflow: hidden; in joomla.css line 1669

```
.moduletable, div[class^="moduletable-"], div[class*=" moduletable-"] {
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the CSS as -

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
}

.moduletable, div[class^="moduletable-"], div[class*=" moduletable-"] {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

This will solve your issue

[image]